# html/css empty space at bottom of the website

Tags: html, css, web

So I have a problem with empty space at bottom of the website. Here is website: [click](https://bdevelops.github.io/feditor/)

Repo of website: https://github.com/bdevelops/feditor

I read questions on stack, tried to find solution, but nothing works.

Sorry for bad English, if it is.

Comment: I'm gonna look in my crystal ball and tell you in a moment.

Comment: You need to clarify your problem. We're not magicians here u know :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS class .box is margin-top:30px or height:100%. This is what makes white space at the bottom of your website

```
box {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%; **//Set it to "auto"
    margin-top: 30px; **//or this one, change it to 0px or remove**
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is working, but at the next page (after selecting file) content and nav are mixing: http://i.imgur.com/2voQrdV.png

That is next problem ;/